# Downloaded proximity chat for among us and now my discord APP isnt working

Tags: javascript, discord

I deleted the  proximity chat and downloaded discord but when I open it I cant click anything, this error keeps showing up and no matter how many time you click "ok" or "exit" it pops up.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue to do with any code.

I recommend just deleting and re-installing the affected app(s).